# Sql Server 2000 - How can I find out what stored procedures are running currently?

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to know what stored procedures are currently running to diagnose some performance problems. How can I find that out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very useful script for analyzing locks and deadlocks: http://www.sommarskog.se/sqlutil/aba_lockinfo.html

It shows procedure or trigger and current statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL Profiler to find that out.

EDIT:
If you can stop the app you are running, you can start SQL Profiler, run the app and look at what's running including stored procedures.

Comment: That won't work because the SP is already running and I'd like to know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do execute sp_who2 to get the list of connections, but then you'll need to run a trace through SQL Profiler on the specific connection to see what it's executing. I don't think that works with queries that are already running though.

Answer (score 2):

[DBCC INPUTBUFFER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187730.aspx) will show you the first 255 characters of input on a spid (you can use sp_who2 to determine the spids you're interested in).  To see the whole command, you can use [::fn_get_sql()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189451.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Using Enterprise Manager, you can open the Management tree section, and choose Current Activity -> Process Info.  Double clicking on a Process ID will show you what that process is running.  If it's a stored procedure, it will not show you the parameters.  For that it would be better to use Brian Kim's suggestion of using the SQL Profiler.