# Check if a stored proc is running?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to check is there any stored proc currently running in SQL Server???

Comment: SQL 2000 or 2005/8?  The tools are quite different between the two.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql Server 2000 - How can I find out what stored procedures are running currently?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129086/sql-server-2000-how-can-i-find-out-what-stored-procedures-are-running-currentl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this once :)

Check out:

[Sql Server 2000 - How can I find out what stored procedures are running currently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129086/sql-server-2000-how-can-i-find-out-what-stored-procedures-are-running-currently)

Answer (score 0):

There's the activity monitor in management studio. There's also sp_who and sp_who2. These will give you an idea of what is running.

However, if you need to programatically find out if a procedure is "in progress" or not to avoid calling it again then I'd consider a flag somewhere to indicate "SPIsRunning" that you set at the start and end of the procedure itself.

Answer (score 0):

Via TSQL you could try evaluating the results of [DBCC INPUTBUFFER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187730.aspx) for each SPID, but it's pretty cumbersome to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
    FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
            CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
    WHERE dest.TEXT LIKE '%YOUR OBJECT NAME HERE%'    
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

---

http://connectsql.blogspot.com/

Comment: this is a nice query, but only tells you the last time the procedure started, not if it is still running

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see activity use SQL Profiler tracing Stored Procedures starting & completed.  Maybe that helps you.