# Currently running stored procedures

Tags: java, sql, database

Is there a way I can determine from Java which stored procedures are currently running on a database?

The answer can involve using Hibernate, although it is not necessary.

My database engine is SQL Server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298187/check-if-a-stored-proc-is-running  & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129086/sql-server-2000-how-can-i-find-out-what-stored-procedures-are-running-currentl

Comment: @VinayVeluri It seems to be the same question, but the link provided in the accepted answers seems not to be working for me(I don'n know the reason why). It is possible that I have not truly understood the suggested solution. But thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can connect to your SQL Server from Java and run an SQL query against it.

See this for example.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/07/sql-server-find-currently-running-query-t-sql/

Then you can take the results returned and process them as you like in your Java code.